# Async storage vs Redux persist , How long does they remain

Tags: react-native, redux-persist

Could you please help me to understand this. I think this is a repeated question and I went with some links too. My Question is about React Native Mobile applications

1. I understood Async has data limit of 6 MB and stores data even you restart the application. My question here is how long the data persists at the backend.  Can the data be stored lifelong until the app is uninstalled?

Or Can we set up some command that tells the ap to store maximum for 1 week and delete it later? 
Or Can I set up 2 Hrs active only and delete it later.

Can you tell any reason to learn Redux persist? What feature does it have more than async storage.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Async Storage is just a storage mechanism to store any data in the form of `<key: value>` pair while redux-persist allows your reducer to fill automatically (more precisely `rehydrate`) whenever your app restarts.

1. Answering your first question, anything that is stored in the async storage will be stored until you delete it by calling the method `removeItem` which is provided by AsyncStorage itself or clear app data from the device settings or uninstall the application itself.
2. Answering your second question, If you want to maintain a session for the stored data then you have to do it programmatically. It can be easily implemented by using redux-persist `manualPersist` prop. Refer to this link,
   `https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#persiststorestore-config-callback`
3. Answering your third question, you can use Async Storage along with redux to store the data of your reducers. You can also use other storage mechanisms in redux-persist. Refer to this link,
   `https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#storage-engines`